# Auth0 spring security issue

Tags: authentication, spring-security, auth0

I've been banging my head against this issue now for a couple days and I'm a bit of a noob with spring security. When implementing Auth0 into the system following their tutorials I get some unexpected behavior. When making a request to api if I have the configuration paramater

```
 auth0.defaultAuth0ApiSecurityEnabled = false
```

then the when I do the OPTIONS pre-ping, I get back a 401 unauthorized code. This doesn't make much sense to me since OPTIONS requests don't get a token injected. To make matters more confusing for me if I switch this flag to true then the OPTIONS preping returns a 200 and then the get request to my endpoint returns 404. This seems hopeful, but the documentation explicitly says that the auth0.defaultAuth0ApiSecurityEnabled configuration should be set to false.

I have the config set up according to their spec as well.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class WebConfig extends Auth0SecurityConfig {

    /**
     *  Our API Configuration - for Profile CRUD operations
     *
     *  Here we choose not to bother using the `auth0.securedRoute` property configuration
     *  and instead ensure any unlisted endpoint in our config is secured by default
     */
    @Override
    protected void authorizeRequests(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api).authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    } 
}
```

I have intentionally set up the endpoint I am trying to hit as non secured as well which has made 0 difference in accessibily. Can anyone shed some light on where they think I might be going wrong with this in Spring security?

Comment: Did you get this sorted or are you still looking for assistance with this situation?

Comment: I believe I got it sorted, but I don't know what I did to fix the issue. usually I would submit an answer to my own question, but since I don't remember what I did, this will just have to remain a bit of a mystery for now. Thanks for following up